# Is libuv under the hood use epoll or select(2) in unix

Tags: node.js, unix, epoll, jquery-select2, libuv

I have been reading around how nodejs uses libuv to perform asynchronous I/O. Reading more about it give me a feeling that it almost sound similar to how select(2) and epoll.

So, my question if I'm using libuv(via node) is it true internally I using select(2) or epoll.

Is libuv is wrapper over select(2) and epoll system call in unix.?

Comment: Did you [read the feature highlights](https://github.com/libuv/libuv#feature-highlights)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

libuv uses the most performant polling mechanism for every platform: that means epoll on Linux, kqueue on macOS and BSDs, /dev/poll on SunOS, etc. One interesting trick libuv does is it uses select() on a thread for some fds kqueue is unable to handle. I gave some details about that here: http://code.saghul.net/index.php/2016/05/24/libuv-internals-the-osx-select2-trick/

Comment: Although in node fs should expose these x-platform "select" or "poll" method.

Comment: I don't see how that would help the vast majority of users.